# Winforms control to show nested shapes

Tags: windows, c#

I'm trying to write a config app where configs are created by connecting and nesting shapes (boxes or circles will).

This sort of thing springs to mind (this is DGML)

[image]

thats actually more complex than I need, but the ability to nest boxes is required, and it may be useful to support arrows between some boxes in some context.

In order for it to be a config app, you then need a user to select a box, and then probably using a context menu decide whether to insert/update/delete new boxes.

DGML actually looks quite nice, but I think its only really available inside VS.

I have looked at syncfusion diagram control, but it feels like its not naturally suited to the nested nature, if anyone has ever tried to create nested diagrams in visio will understand, you can make it look nested, but the control itself doesnt seem to understand....so I'm concerned I'll write a layer on top of the control just to manage this.
(I'm pretty ignorant of it though)

any ideas?

P.S. DGML is very pretty, a crude rectangle inside rectangle next to rectange sort of thing would functionally be sufficient, even if it would look clunky

Answer (score 0):

GoDiagram has what you want and much more: https://godiagram.com/winforms/latest/samples/#groups